# Creation of a compression algorithm so I can access the data to interpolate later?

Tags: c++, arrays, compression, interpolation

The following is a more elaborative conjecture on what i wish to achieve; here is how far I reached;

A 3d grid, about 303030, or a 3d array, so i can define a function of R3 -> R f(x, y, z) = v More precisely, where x, y, z € [0, N] of float values so for f(0.5, 0.5, 0.5) the result would be the trilinear interpolation for the points (0,0,0), (0,0,1), (0,1,0), (0,1,1), (1,0,0), (1,0,1), (1,1,0) and (1,1,1). With v is equal to the value stored in the array if x, y, and z are integer values, or the trilinear interpolation of the closest points in the array where N_i is the number of points - 1 in the i dimension of the array; x € [0, N_x], y € [0, N_y], and z € [0, N_z]. Now let's Imagine a 1d array(which does not exist, only integer indices), one can make up a value by interpolation between closest actual values, and can extend this to 2d, though if you try to get a value for the position 0.3864 for positions 0 and 1 you need the 4 closest points in the end you can extend to any number of dimensions. Providing the values at (0,0), (0,1), (1,0) and (1,1). n is the number of dimensions which have a non-integer coordinate, but you get the point with a bilinear interpolation, and you'll need exactly 2n points where n is the number of dimensions.

Simplified;
I have a 3d grid of floats which via I wish to access this values in parallel by the thousands In random positions. To which then I want to convert this memory bound process into cpu bound; by flattening the 3d array, and approximate it with a finite Fourier expansion or something similar. Then calculate the values at the required positions of this flattened data and use the calculated values to do the trilinear interpolation. Conclusively, the original code would just access the values by their array indices, one by one. as the values are being accessed randomly and they are far away from each other in memory; which i'm looking for a suitable strategy to access (or calculate if possible) the values based on an index.

Comment: Please confirm: The array is **not** sparse?

Comment: To my knowledge which may albeit be naive indeed, no.